# unexpected token using `` in jsx

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
<Link to=`/event/${event_id}?start=${startDate}&?end=${endDate}` target="_blank">
..content
</Link>
```

what's wrong with above snytax? I spot nothing wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Warp your `` inside brackets since this is Javascript and JSX interprets Javascript only when it's between brackets.

```
<Link to={`/event/${event_id}?start=${startDate}&?end=${endDate}`} target="_blank">
..content
</Link>
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Tharaka 's answer you should add a property 
`rel='noopener noreferrer'`
See here [why](https://mathiasbynens.github.io/rel-noopener/)

```
<Link to={`/event/${event_id}?start=${startDate}&?end=${endDate}`} target="_blank" rel='noopener noreferrer'>
..content
</Link>
```

It's considered as a best practice.